# Zend Framework 2: TableGateway

Tags: php, zend-framework2, where-clause, between, tablegateway

I am using the TableGateway from Zend Framework 2. My problem is that I cannot get the between function to work.

This is my code that I have for now, the output is just nothing:

```
public function fetchBetween($startDate, $endDate)
{
    $where = new Where();
    $where->between('date', $startDate, $endDate);

    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select($where);
    return $resultSet;
}
```

I am calling this function to get the date between two dates.

```
$this->getCalendarTable()->fetchBetween('4-04-2014', '30-05-2014');
```

[image: PHPMyadmin table]

This is the query that it has to be and in phpmyadmin it is giving back data so there is nothing wrong with the query or the databank:

```
SELECT * FROM `klj_agenda` WHERE date BETWEEN '1-05-2014' AND '30-05-2014'
```

Comment: Use ZendDeveloperTools module to debug queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the query: 2014-05-01 instead of 01-05-2014

Comment: Because I didn't know the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using TableGateWay, and I'm by no means an expert and have 'stolen' the code from a book by Ralf Eggert. He is always using tableGateWay->selectWith($select) and this works.
What the difference is with your code, I would need to investigate.